# ChromeCast :How to set when user disconnect to with google cast and receiver show home screen in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, chromecast

im still new with ChromeCast cast and still playing around with google cast ios examples. But when i disconnect the app with the google cast,the receiver still show the media that we cast. How to make its totally disconnected and show home screen?

Thanks!

Comment: It's **Chromecast**.

Comment: Im Sorry.I forgot to add this 2 lines below which is fix my issue. 
deviceManager.LeaveApplication ();   deviceManager.StopApplication ();

Answer (score 0):

What receiver are you using, is it your own custom receiver or the Deafult/Styled receiver? In the latter, we already take care of that if you are the last connected sender and explicitly disconnect yourself. In the former, you need to do that on the receiver yourself, look at the receiver documentation for [onSenderDisconnected](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager#onSenderDisconnected)() call back.

Comment: its a default reveiver

Comment: can we do that in sender it self? because even i set it disconnected,media still play in the screen.

Comment: Then there is something else going on that is stopping the default receiver to do the right thing, you need to figure that out first. As to answer your question whether you can do that on the sender side or not, the answer is yes, it is doable but requires a fair amount of work since each sender needs to know how many other senders are connected and have the receiver broadcast a message to all senders when one sender is implicitly or explicitly is disconnected, etc. That is why the proper place is in the receiver.